# How to write constraint when the variable to be solved is an index variable of a list using or-tools cp_model?

Tags: python, or-tools, constraint-programming, cp-sat

The straightforward code below is not work beacause of the datatype issue:

"TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not _SumArray"

```py
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model

model = cp_model.CpModel()

TableA = [...][...] # 2-d list, constant table
TableB = [...] # 1-d list, constant table

rowIdx = model.NewIntVar(0, idxLen - 1, 'rowIdx')
columnIdx = model.NewIntVar(0, idxLen - 1, 'columnIdx')

for i in range(constraint_num):
    model.Add(TableA[i][rowIdx * idxLen + columnIdx] == TableB[i])
```

I want to use a constant list to encode similar constraints on variables, so that I can use loops to add constraints like above, is there any way to use variable or their linear expression access multidimensional list when adding constraints? Or is there a method like `solver.Element()` from `ortools.constraint_solver.pywrapcp` in cp_model?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

1) Look at http://google.github.io/or-tools/python/ortools/sat/python/cp_model.html#cp_model.CpModel.AddElement

You will need to create an intermediate variable for the index.

2) If the array is constant, then you can filter the list of admissible indices.
Then write

```
model.AddLinearExpressionInDomain(rowIdx * idxLen + columnIdx, cp_model.Domain.FromValues([list of admissible_indices]))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Laurent! Maybe I didn't describe the question clearly, so I updated the question body like above. Is there a method like `solver.Element()` from `ortools.constraint_solver.pywrapcp` in cp_model, which can help me use variable or their linear expression access multidimensional list when adding constraints? I have read all the methods of cp_model module in the link you provided, but I have not found similar method. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: There are no multi-dimensional element. If you array of values is constant, I recommend using a table constraint with tuples (i, j, matrix[i][j]).